# How to find the source of the code when it says element.style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea how to find the source of this element style codes. Such as at the right part of the Chrome Element Inspector Tool it shows this CSS code:

```
element.style {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 486px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
}
```

and at the left part there is this :

```
<div draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 486px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171);"></div>
```

I've looked into the modules files but I only see JavaScript and HTML files without the above line?

Comment: Seems to be added inline through some javascript plugin.

Comment: Yes element.style means it's an inline style. If you haven't added an inline style then it is being added by a js plugin

Answer (score 2):

`element.style` just tells you that the styles are added to the element through the `style` attribute or JavaScript, but not via an external CSS file. You might check you JS files for these properies if you can't find the them in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

That's because those styles are **inline**.  Meaning they use the `style` attribute of an HTML tag to define its CSS properties.  That CSS is not in a file or elsewhere.  It is being defined "within" the element it is being applied to.

Answer (score 0):

That specific line of HTML doesn't need to exist in any file for that div to exist in the DOM. For example, this Javascript would create a div just like that:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('draggable', 'false');
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.overflow = 'hidden';
div.style.cssText += 'left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 486px; height: 200px; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171);';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Try searching your JS files for `-webkit-user-select`. That style property is used rarely enough that it should help you find the relevant section of Javascript code.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought, but I checked the modules Javascript and I can't find the code: -webkit-user-select and checked JS file on the template with no luck also the javascript on the software alone but there are like 10 JS files and have no idea what or where to find this codes, in order to edit them through CSS, it is possible?If not how can I edit it? Through Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem, and it turned out that AdBlocker (browser plug-in) was inserting in-line styles to hide images on my site that it thought were ads. Try disabling some or all of your browser plug-ins and see if they are interfering with the way your page is rendered.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but if you click on the small '+' icon on the top right of the inspector, it lets you add your styles to a css class that is already attached to your element. When yo do so, you will be able to click on the inspector-stylesheet link that appears on the right of the defined style. I think thats the closest you can get to defining some sort of temporary stylesheet that will contain all of your custom styles.

Thats what I do for quick testing. Set some classes in the html, then add more custom styles in the inspector side panel - because its easy to edit and/pick colors in there. Then open inspector-stylesheet and copy them all once I am done.